# Can I run 2 Bitcoin nodes with the same wallets?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet

We have a full Bitcoin node with its wallets on the server. The issue is that the majority of our wallets were synchronized long time ago. For us, it would seem that this synchronization task can take a significant amount of time in which the Bitcoin node will be unreachable for all other requests and our server will be unavailable for users.

We think about replicating the current Bitcoin node on the separate server and synchronize wallets there. After this process will be finished we will copy wallets back to the origin server.

Is it doable? Or we can't have the same wallets on two different Bitcoin nodes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable. You can run as many nodes with the same wallets as you want.
I imagine you want to do this because the synchronisation process will be faster on another node?
After the process is done, you will have to copy the complete **blockchain data**, not the wallet itself.

You might want to consider checking for what your bottleneck is - could be the hard disk or the CPU, or in some cases the internet bandwidth.

Comment: by `complete blockchain data` you mean full `.bitcoin` folder with wallets, blocks etc.?

Comment: during wallets synchronization, our bitcoin node stops to respond on any other requests (creating transactions, loading wallets balance...). So, I tend to think that the bottleneck here is the node itself. That's why would like to perform a sync on the separate server

Comment: I think the whole .bitcoin folder should suffice, yes. It's been a while since I've done that so I'm not 100% sure. If you do it correctly, you won't be prompted to rebuild the indexes. Have you checked the disk and CPU usage?

Comment: Yes, we did. During the process, one core of CPU is busy for 100%.

Comment: I'm not sure why there's only one core at 100%. All cores should be doing the work. Anyway, if the CPU is at 100%, that means the CPU is the bottleneck and you need a faster CPU for faster synchronization times.
You should also update to the newest bitcoind version and use more cache (memory) with -dbcache option. The default is 450 I think, you can bump that to 5000.

Comment: ok, I will keep investigating. thanks